# Error when processing PDFs with Lambda using the OpenAIEmbeddings class from the LangChain project

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, langchain

I'm developing an AWS Lambda function that processes PDFs and then ingests them. I'm using the [LangChain project](https://github.com/mayooear/gpt4-pdf-chatbot-langchain) as a base, which helps in embedding the text extracted from PDFs using OpenAI's models.

However, I'm running into an issue when creating an instance of the `OpenAIEmbeddings` class:

`const embeddings = new OpenAIEmbeddings();`

**Error:**

```
{
  "statusCode": 500,
  "body": "\"Error processing messages and ingesting PDFs: Error: (Azure) OpenAI API key not found\""
}
```

I suspect the error might be related to the OpenAIEmbeddings instantiation or somewhere around it. The PDF processing step seems to be successful, but the embedding phase is problematic.

**Here is a snippet from my code:**

```
const OpenAIEmbeddings = require("langchain/embeddings/openai");

// ...

async function processPDF(pdfFilename) {
  try {
   // Fetch the PDF content from S3 using the new method
   const command = new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: S3_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: pdfFilename,
  });
  const pdfContent = await s3Client.send(command);
  const tempFilePath = path.join('/tmp', path.basename(pdfFilename));
  await fs.writeFile(tempFilePath, pdfContent.Body); // Directly save the buffer

    // Load and split the PDF
    const loader = new PDFLoader(tempFilePath); // Use the path to the saved PDF
    const rawDocs = await loader.load();
    const textSplitter = new RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter({
      chunkSize: 1000,
      chunkOverlap: 200,
    });
    const docs = await textSplitter.splitDocuments(rawDocs);
    // Generate embeddings and ingest into Pinecone
    const embeddings = new OpenAIEmbeddings();

    const index = pinecone.Index(PINECONE_INDEX_NAME);

    await PineconeStore.fromDocuments(docs, embeddings, {
      pineconeIndex: index,
      namespace: PINECONE_NAME_SPACE,
      textKey: "text",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error processing and ingesting PDF: ${pdfFilename}. Error: ${error}`);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have insights about what might be causing the problem? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please setup environment variable key OPENAI_API_KEY as environment variable or load it in the code